# Image download issue using Python

Tags: python, iteration, imagedownload

I am downloading images using `URLs` through python using `requests.get()` function. When I gave a single URL to this function it downloads. But when given some `1000 URL's` in for loop, some of the resultant images gets corrupt. But if I open up the `URL` of a corrupted image in the browser we can see that image so there seems to be no problem with `URLs`. Why it would be happening?

Comment: Could you provide your code to let us check if problem exists?

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

it appears to be some anti-spider countermeasures. All you need to do is to decorate your HTTP HEADER in Python. By default the "agent" segment in HTTP Header tell the website they are "python" :)

in python, you can try with:

```
# _*_coding:utf-8 _*_
# @Time    : 2019/4/22 15:51
# @Author  : Shek 
# @FileName: m2.py
# @Software: PyCharm

import requests

# header modify function
def get_header(agent, referer, host):
# just for example, you can crawl it from your Google Chrome Browser with F12
    header = {
        'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8',
        'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
        'Accept-Language': 'zh-CN,zh;q=0.9',
        'Connection': 'keep-alive',
        'Host': host,
        'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0',
        'Referer': referer,
        'Cookie':'bla bla bla',
        'User-Agent': agent
    }
    return header

# requests part
req_session = requests.Session()
req = req_session.get(url='your.url', headers=get_header(agent='your.agent',referer='your.referer',host='your.host'), timeout=10)

# save part
with open('filename.jpg', 'w') as file_wr:
    file_wr.write(req.content)

file_wr.close()
```